# Vejo a pergunta nas "perguntas mais recentes" porém a mesma foi "voluntariamente removida pelo autor"

Tags: bug, status-intencional

Hmmm... um probleminha de "cache"... fiquei dando refresh nas "perguntas mais recentes" até que finalmente, alguns minutos depois, a pergunta saiu da lista.

Tem como melhorar essa experiência para o usuário?

[image: Pergunta inexistente aparecendo na lista de perguntas mais recentes]

[image: Página que aparece ao clicar na pergunta]

Comment: Duvido que mudem isso, teriam de invalidar o cache da lista a cada exclusão (e isso potencialmente pode pesar muito em sites movimentados). Geralmente a lista acaba sendo atualizada em poucos minutos, então não é grave. E quando você tiver mais reputação, o link vai funcionar, mostrando a pergunta excluída. Pode até ser útil.